# How to add a login screen before the Home screen in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, authentication, navigation, stack-navigator

My code is currently stuck in the top of the home screen.
However, I would like to let you go to the home screen when I press the login button on the login screen.
I hope there is no Top Navigation or Bottom Tab Navigation on the login screen here.

[Current Homescreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41wPk.png)

Below is my code.
Login is an import of screen parts.

Please help me.

app.js

```js
export default function App() {
  
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={authContext}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Tab.Navigator
          screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
              let iconName;

              if (route.name === 'Home') {
                iconName = focused ? 'ios-home' : 'ios-home-outline';
              } else if (route.name === 'Purchase') {
                iconName = focused ? 'ios-list-circle' : 'ios-list';
              } else if (route.name === 'Wish List') {
                iconName = focused ? 'ios-star' : 'ios-star-outline'
              }

              // You can return any component that you like here!
              return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
            },
          })}
          tabBarOptions={{
            activeTintColor: '#32cd32',
            inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
            
          }}
        >
          <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeStackScreen} />
          <Tab.Screen name="Wish List" component={WishListStackScreen} />
          <Tab.Screen name="Purchase" component={PurchaseStackScreen} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </AuthContext.Provider>

  );
};
```

Comment: Refer https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/#implement-the-logic-for-restoring-the-token.. Instead of nesting Login Component, conditionally add Login in a Stack.Navigator

Comment: @Hariks
When I refer to Docs, it says that if I want to use tap navigation and bottom tab navigation together, create a container with tap navigation and then insert a stack screen with the component value. So I made a code with this structure. What should I do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you should first make a **stack navigator** in **app.js** with the login screen and the homepage in the stack:

```
<NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
           <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
           <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
       </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

When you press the button on the login screen you should do this when the user is authenticated:

```
<Button onPress={() => {navigation.navigate('Home')}}
```

Then on the homepage you should add the tabnavigator

Comment: If you look at my code, I'm using a stack screen and a tab screen together. I put in a stack screen as a component of a tab screen. I need a login screen without a tab screen and a stack screen.

Comment: I'm aware of that but if you don't want the tab navigator on the login page you should first make a stack navigator like I showed you above (so you navigate to the login screen) then make the button go to the homepage and add the tabnavigator to your homepage

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. However, if i add the code you told me, the error appears that the tab navigator and stack navigator cannot be used together.

Comment: you can't use the together indeed, that's why you need the stack navigator in the app.js file and the tab navigator on your home page

Comment: This is what I mean: [link](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/)

Comment: Thank you for the link you sent. Is there a way to add a login screen to the first screen while maintaining my code?

Comment: I solved it! I changed the structure as you said.